# Comparing adjectives to describe a noun

Tags: adjectives

I get the use of Aの方がB, but so far all the examples I've seen are strictly used for comparing nouns.
So my question is, what if I'm trying to compare adjectives? As in, trying to explain that one adjective is more suitable to describe a noun than another one.
Some examples of what I mean:

> This apple tastes more bitter than it tastes sweet.

or similarly

> To say this apple tastes bitter would be more fitting than to say it tastes sweet.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to compare two adjectives, I think you can try using [というより](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A-to-iu-yori-meaning/)　So that it becomes:

> このリンゴは甘いというより苦いです。

Comment: No you can't say the last sentence...

Comment: @broccolifacemask-cloth Thanks! I have already edited my response.